# Advance drag and drop with jquery

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

Hello guys i am new to jquery. I want to create a drag and drop in which i can drop an image on a specific region and the image is cropped to the size of that div, when i drop another image on the div then the first image must be removed. Please help in achieving this. If i am not clear then please take a look at http://www.shutterfly.com/photo-gifts/custom-iphone-cases and then select an case and go to personalization you will get the idea.

This is my first time on stackoverflow. Please let me know if i am not clear to you.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example using jquery and jquery-ui:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".image").draggable({
    drag:function(){
        $(this).css({opacity:0.5});
    }
});
$(".container").droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    var img = ui.draggable[0];
      var chld = $(this).children().first();
      if(chld && $(chld).hasClass("image")){
          $(chld).css({width:null,height:null});
          $(".images").append(chld);
      }
      $(this).html("");
      $(img).css({opacity:1,width:"100px",height:"100px",top:"0px",left:"0px"});
      $(this).append(img);
   }
});
```

});

See the example in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Elak/pfe2p/5/

Basically you just have to control what happens when an image gets dropped on a "droppable" element.

Resizing can be done by applying styles. You could also define a css class and assign it to the image via $(..).addClass("yourclass"), and remove the class via .removeClass("..") if you want to reset the image. In my example I did that manually via .css() which is not very "clean".

note: in latest jquery, dragging images does currently not work in IE10. Thats why I used v1.7